# Clean walls without removing its paint

Tags: cleaning, home, paint

Now and then , the wall gets dirty even after regular cleaning with dry cloth and other equipments. But greasy spots on wall cannot be cleaned without using damp cloth with little soap. This leads to wearing of paints and makes it dull. I need hack to clean the grease without affecting the wall paint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Paint is usually hard to clean unless you have special paints. Some things you can try are:

- Using sponges not cloths. This promotes dabbing not rubbing which removes paint.
- Use mild soaps or even no soap. Yes, dish soap is good for grease removal, but it is not good for paint. So use mild soaps and try to extract the oil from the paint. Using flour or cornstarch on the wall helps drag the oil out and then dabbing clean with a wet sponge works. Not using soap at all helps keep paint intact.
- Lessen exposure to moisture on the paint to as short as possible and try not to rub or dab paint very much. Also, try not to wait to treat stains clean them immediately.

Comment: Using cornstarch or flour sounds good. thank you. But they can absorb the greasiness , what about the spot left after it? Do you think I can use normal cloth or sponge with small amount of soap to clean it?

Comment: @Vibhu Of course! But I would go for the sponge, as the rag will promote rubbing off the paint. In the future, better paint would be a must.